# RHEL7 text-only installation

Tags: linux, rhel, console, startup

I want to install RHEL7 in purely text-only mode. Although I added the `inst.text` and  `inst.cmdline` kernel option (since I want it to install from kickstart) it still requires more than a console as it is pushing its output through the framebuffer.

Is there a way to force it to disable the framebuffer entirely and have everything visible to a plain console in text on Red Hat 7? There seems to be no `nofb` option.

Comment: Appending "text" on the install options did the trick on CentOS 7 install for me too...

Answer (score 4):

I was using Centos 7.  On the install, I hit tab to bring up the install options, and appended "text" on them.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I did. (add nomodeset)

```
 label CentOS 7 x86_64
   KERNEL linux/centos/7/x86_64/vmlinuz
   initrd linux/centos/7/x86_64/initrd.img
   APPEND nomodeset lang=us keymap=us noipv6 ip=dhcp ks=http://pxe.example.com/pxe/linux/centos/ks7.cfg
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me. Please change the values as per your environment.

This is my PXE file `/var/lib/tftpboot/pxelinux.cfg/default` parameters :-

```
KERNEL distros/CentOS_7.1_64/images/pxeboot/vmlinuz
INITRD distros/CentOS_7.1_64/images/pxeboot/initrd.img
APPEND ks=http://192.168.1.100/kscfg/ks_CentOS_7.1_64.cfg ksdevice=link
```

Additionally, I have used `cmdline` in my kickstart file instead of `text`.

Answer (score 0):

If you (like me) are using this on a server from a management module web-interface and you see everything, but can't type or move the cursor, the framebuffer is actually not the problem. [This bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=850785) is and the workaround is to append `usbcore.autosuspend=-1` to the kernel command line.

For some possible candidates on fixing framebuffer/video issues, there are few interesting parameters in [the Installation Guide](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Installation_Guide/chap-anaconda-boot-options.html#sect-boot-options-installer): `inst.xdriver=vesa` or `inst.usefbx`.

Apart from those there's also `nomodeset`, which worked for me after the installation, where I could verify there's no `/dev/fb*` device, which is said to be an indicator of framebuffer's presence.

Answer (score -1):

press ESC on first boot screen and input "linux text"
boot:linux text

Comment: isn't this what [was already posted](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/143816/117549)?